# Query to find type of customer of type B ONLY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DETAILS table having

```
detail_id, customer_id and type
```

columns.

type can either be 'A' or 'B'.

customer can have both type.

Goal is to find customer of Type B ONLY.

i.e output should not give customer details having both type.

| detail_id | customer_id | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | c1 | A |
| 1 | c2 | B |
| 2 | c1 | B |
| 3 | c3 | A |

The query should give only c2 as output.

Please let me know If I can achieve this without using 2 select statements.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the following lines should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    d.*
FROM
    DETAILS d
WHERE
    type = 'B'
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM DETAILS d2
                    WHERE d.customer_id = d2.customer_id
                    AND d2.type = 'A')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query, which aggregates the type_id:

```
SELECT
      customer_id ,
      listagg( type,'') within Group (order by type)  " type_id"   
from [tablename]
      group by customer_id
      having listagg( type,'') within Group (order by type) ='B'
```

To complete my Anwser. Here is the Code for mysql:

```
 SELECT
      customer_id ,
      group_concat( type,'') as " type_id"   
 from [Tablename]
      group by customer_id
      having group_concat( type,'') ='B'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.*
FROM DETAILS d  
WHERE type = 'B'    
AND customer_id NOT IN 

                   (SELECT customer_id
                    FROM DETAILS
                    WHERE type = 'A');
```